# Most performant alternative to SELECT COUNT(*) using PDO and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've read previously that `SELECT COUNT(*)` is not performant in `MySQL` and should be regularly avoided. (As a side question, is this only the case for a large number of rows?)

I'm using `PHP Data Objects (PDO)` to access `MySQL`.

How should I be counting rows with performance considerations in mind?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` usually checks the primary key index and counts that. Also, if you are using MyISAM, you can get a precise count by using `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using **MyISAM tables, it does not hit performance**. MySQL **caches** number of rows in MyISAM tables. This is why it is able to instantly answer COUNT(*). In this case, MySQL would simply read number of rows in the table from stored value.

**[EDIT]: From MySQL Performance Blog:**

For InnoDB: If you have query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IMAGE WHERE USER_ID=5` this query will be executed same way both for MyISAM and Innodb tables by performing index rage scan. This can be faster or slower both for MyISAM and Innodb depending on various conditions.

In real applications there are much more queries of second type rather than first type so it is typically not as bad problem as it may look. Most typically count of rows is needed by admin tools which may show it in table statistics, it may also be used in application stats to show something like “We have 123.345 users which have uploaded 1.344.656 images” but these are normally easy to remove.

> So remember Innodb is not slow for ALL COUNT(*) queries but only for very specific case of COUNT(*) query without WHERE clause.

Also interesting read for you:

- [Count(*) vs Count(col) Performance](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/)
- [Count(*) for Innodb Tables Performance](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/)

Comment: Ah, well, if only I were using MyISAM. I'm using InnoDB.

Comment: Should have specified earlier.

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT(*)`, as far as I am aware is actually more efficient than using `COUNT(columnname)`. If you are looking for a row count, these will be way more efficient then trying to count rows via a PDO or MySQL (which would most likely have to pull all rows, given that you are not just executing a `select` with `count()`).

I am unsure of any other way to get a count out, but that should be just fine, depending on what you are doing. The main item you should concentrate on is making sure your tables have proper `indexes` setup as this will dramatically increase the MySQL speed etc, if properly done.

Answer (score 1):

PDO is not really relevant in running a specific count query. PDO is just how you connect to MySQL. You should not use count(colname) if you just need a row count, you should use count(*). If you specify colname and that column is not specified as NOT NULL, it will be slow.
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

MyISAM tables cache the count, so a count(*) on a MyISAM table is always immediate. InnoDB takes a while, since the state of the table can be in flux and you end up with an estimate. You can do a count(colname) for InnoDB, where colname is an auto increment field. That will be fairly fast and accurate, although never as fast as count(*) on MyISAM tables.

Comment: PDO is, I think, somewhat relevant since it's very difficult to get a row count using PDO.

Comment: It's harder to get a found count with PDO, not a row count. A row count is just another query like any other, it just returns a single row as the result set.